Why are cyclic dependencies/imports a huge topic for type checking?
Both MyPy and ArkType cite cyclic dependencies/imports as either a challenge to handle or pride themselves on handling them. One is a type checker for Python while the other is a type checker for TypeScript.
Why is this such an important topic for type checking?

This may be a better question for [langdev.SE].
